# Cannot display queried features in dojo dataGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I am creating a web map application that users will be able to query for layer features, in this case land properties, using a form search and the results should be displayed in two ways:
1)The property features that meet the search criteria will be highlighted on the map (I have this working)
2)The attributes of the each property that meet the search criteria will be listed in a dojo dataGrid. (I cannot get this to work - I just get an error message "Sorry an error occurred" in my dataGrid.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

## Query form html: (I don't think there are any problems here)

```
    <div form id="queryForm" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="overflow:auto;" data-dojo-props="title:'Search For Properties', selected:true">
      <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Acquisition Number: </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="ACNO" autocomplete="on"></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Property Name: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Name" autocomplete="on"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Type of Property: </td>
         <td><select multiple name="Land_Type" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
            <option value="Access Site">Access Site</option>
            <option value="Conservation Easement">Conservation Easement</option>
            <option value="Depredation">Depredation</option>
            <option value="Fish Hatchery">Fish Hatchery</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="WHA">WHA</option>
            <option value="WHAS">WHAS</option>
            <option value="WMA">WMA</option>
            <option value="WMU">WMU</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>Owner: </td>
          <td><select multiple name="Owner" id="Owner" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
            <option value="BLM">U.S. Bureau of Land Management</option>
            <option value="COE">U.S. Army Corps of Engineers</option>
            <option value="County">County</option>
            <option value="IDFG">Idaho Fish and Game</option>
            <option value="IDL">Idaho Department of Lands</option>
            <option value="IFWF">Idaho Fish and Wildlife Foundation</option>
            <option value="ITD">Idaho Transportation Department</option>
            <option value="Private">Private</option>
            <option value="RMEF">Rocky Mountain Elk Foundation</option>
            <option value="U of I">University of Idaho</option>
            <option value="USBR">U.S. Bureau of Reclamation</option>
            <option value="USFS">U.S. Forest Service</option>
            <option value="USFWS">U.S.Fish Wildlife Services</option>
          </select></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Entitlement Type: </td>
          <td><select multiple name="ADM_CODE" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
            <option value="Agreement">Agreement</option>
            <option value="Depredation">Depredation</option>
            <option value="Easement">Easement</option>
            <option value="Lease">Lease</option>
            <option value="Permit">Permit</option>
            <option value="Own">Own</option>
            <option value="Will">Will</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Acres: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Acres" autocomplete="off" style="width:100px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" id="submitButton" value=" Search"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Clear Results"> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>    
    </div>
```

## dojo DataGrid html: (don't think there are any problems here)

```
    <div id="resultsPane" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="bottom" design="headline" overflow="hidden" gutters="false" splitter="true">
    <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsid="grid" id="grid" clientSort="true" rowSelector="20px" sortInfo="-4">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="25" field="OBJECTID_1" formatter="makeZoomButton">
              <img id="zoomImg" alt="+" src="images/magnifier.png">
            </th>
            <th width="auto" field="ACNO">Acquisition Number</th>
            <th width="auto" field="Name">Property Name</th>
            <th width="auto" field="Land_Type">Type of Property</th>
            <th width="auto" field="Owner">Land Owner</th>
            <th width="auto" field="ADM_CODE">Entitlement Type</th>
            <th width="auto" field="Acres">Acres</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

## query JavaScript (I believe the issue lies in the last code block - "Create data store and bind to grid").

```
    function doQuery() {
  //initialize query task
  var query, queryTask;
  var grid, store;
  queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("https://fishandgame.idaho.gov/gis/rest/services/Data/IDFGManagedLands/MapServer/9");

  //initialize query
  query = new esri.tasks.Query();
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = ["ACNO", "Name", "Land_Type", "Owner", "ADM_CODE", "Acres"];
  
  var theOwner = $( "#Owner option:selected" ).val();
  //query.where = "Owner = " + theOwner;
  var theWhere = "Owner = '" + theOwner + "'";
  //alert(theWhere);
  query.where = theWhere;
  queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
}

function showResults(results) {
  //alert(results.length);
  var map = _maps[0];
  map.graphics.clear()
  
  //Highlight the features that have been returned.
  var highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([230,0,0]),1);
  //Obtain the results in the form of a FeatureSet.
  var featureSet = results.features;
  
  //alert(featureSet.length);
  
  //Loop through each of the features returned, pull out the attributes, and add them to the item array.
  var items = []; //all items to be stored in data store
  for (var i=0, il=results.features.length; i<il; i++) {
    var graphic = featureSet[i];
    graphic.setSymbol(highlightSymbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
    items.push(featureSet[i].attributes);
  }  

  //Create data object to be used in store
  var data = {
  identifier: "OBJECTID_1", //This field needs to have unique values
  label: "OBJECTID_1",
  };
        
  //Create data store and bind to grid.
  store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: {items: data}});
  grid.setStore(store);
  //hideLoading(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique identifier, OBJECTID_1, is not included in the original query.

Add OBJECTID_1 to the query.outfields:

```
function doQuery() {
  //initialize query task
  var query, queryTask;
  queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("https://fishandgame.idaho.gov/gis/rest/services/Data/IDFGManagedLands/MapServer/9");

  //initialize query
  query = new esri.tasks.Query();
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = ["OBJECTID_1","ACNO", "Name", "Land_Type", "Owner", "ADM_CODE", "Acres"];

  var theOwner = $( "#Owner option:selected" ).val();
  //query.where = "Owner = " + theOwner;
  var theWhere = "Owner = '" + theOwner + "'";
  //alert(theWhere);
  query.where = theWhere;
  queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
}

function showResults(results) {
  var map = _maps[0];
  map.graphics.clear();

  //Highlight the features that have been returned.
  var highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([230,0,0]),1);

  //Obtain the results in the form of a FeatureSet.
  var featureSet = results.features;

  //Loop through each of the features returned, pull out the attributes, and add them to the item array.
  var items = []; //all items to be stored in data store
  for (var i=0, il=featureSet.length; i<il; i++) {
                var graphic = featureSet[i];
                graphic.setSymbol(highlightSymbol);
                map.graphics.add(graphic);
                items.push(featureSet[i].attributes);
  }

  //Create data object to be used in store
  var data = {
    identifier: "OBJECTID_1", //This field needs to have unique values
    label: "OBJECTID_1",
    items:items
  };

  //Create data store and bind to grid.
  store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data:data });
  grid.setStore(store);
  hideLoading();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign your items to your store. I think your code should go like this,

```
store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
  'identifier': 'OBJECTID_1',
  'label': 'OBJECTID_1',
  'items': items
})
```

Comment: Dang.  This does not seem to solve my problem.  I know it is working properly through map.graphics.add(graphics) because the selected features are highlighted on the map. I can see the grid with the proper field labels but it still doesn't get populated with the selected feature attributes. I'll keep at it.